# Capture Snapshot image from video in AxWindowsMediaPlayer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am looking for a function to take a screenshot from an embedded Windows Media Player control in a VB.NET Windows form. I am currently using the following function; it works fine, but the problem is that `x` and `y` are different on each screen so it would be better if I could use a function in the `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` control itself, like `.Capture()` or a similar method.

```
Private Function TakeImage(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal Width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer) As Bitmap
    Dim Img As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Img)
    g.CopyFromScreen(X, Y, 0, 0, Img.Size)
    g.Dispose()
    Return Img
End Function

Dim bmp As Bitmap = TakeImage(x, y - 20, AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Width, AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Height)
bmp.Save("E:\pics\" & i.ToString & ".jpg", Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Comment: you can either provide an answer to the question or keep your morals for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `Ctl.PointToScreen()` to get an absolute screen point for `CopyFromScreen`.

I would get the `AxWMP.PointToScreen` in the procedure each time since the form could move. Pass them to `CopyFromScreen` and see if that works.  I am not sure if it expects X,Y relative to the app, form or what but Screen, does mean screen.

Comment: thanks but pointtoscreen is returning 0,0 of the form position

Comment: that doesnt sound right...a pic on a form, btn.click = `lbl.Text = pic.PointToScreen(pic.Location).ToString` gives a screen relative location as I move the form. I also loaded the AxWMP and it still returned screen relative coords whether on the bare form or a panel.  Got anything weird going on in the form?

Comment: yeah it worked fine now. but i wonder what is the point parameter passed to PointToScreen does

Comment: It is the Point to convert.  BTW you will get different/wrong results with `Me.PointToScreen(WMP.Location).ToString` vs `AxWmp.PointToScreen(...)` you can add relativeness thru the control invoking it.